# extract an object from another file based on its path

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which contains paths to certains files that i need to extract from them an object and i don't know how.

my result output is like this :

```
[ 'xxx/yyy/file1.js',
  'xxx/yyy/file2.js',
  'xxx/yyy/file3.js' ]
```

and inside each of them i got a block of code that define routes like this :

```
module.exports = {
  xxx: '/xxx',
  routes: [{
    yyy: '/',
    ccc: {
      x: {
      },
    },
  }],
};
```

i need to get the object inside the module.exports

Comment: use triple dot (`...`). You can refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure when you're doing this (run-time or build-time) or the platform, but if you're on node or using webpack you can use

```js
const module = require(path);
```

You can also read the files in with node's fs module and parse them with JSON.parse()

This seems a little weird to be honest. If you know the paths ahead of time just import them with require or import